# Cmd script in shell_exec fails to run

Tags: php, windows, cmd, shell-exec

I need to add users to a local windows group via PHP. This is my attempt:

```
<?php
$output shell_exec('net localgroup groupname /add domain\user');
echo $output;
?>
```

I get `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\acc.php on line 2`. I suppose it's some escaping issue but I can't figure it out. Tried double backslash `\\` but didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to assign the returned value to `$output` variable

```
$output = shell_exec('net localgroup groupname /add domain\user');
```

Comment: Ohhh! My! God! No comment. I'm always suprised how people can be that blind and now here I am. Thanks.

Comment: @fishmong3r, No problem, it happens with everyone. If this was your problem & if my answer solved your problem, then accept it as answer.

Comment: Yes, it was. I will do in 6 minutes.